# Python Project works fine in Spyder IDE but does not work in VScode

Tags: python, project, virtual-environment

I've been working on a python project for a while. I've recently started to switch from the Spyder IDE to VScode. My project works completly fine when I run in spyder. However if I open it and run it in VScode there are errors that have to do with the PIL Module. I suspect that the errors are due to updates to the modules. Now I've started to wonder wether spyder creates a virtual environment when you create a project. However I have very little experience with these things and I'm sure that I didn't create a venv myself if there should be one. Maybe someone more experienced can tell me. I'll gladly provide more detail about the errors and such if that should be necessary.

I've tried loading the project multiple times in both IDEs. However the situation described above has not changed.

Comment: how did you install spyder, if it is part of anaconda, it may be using a different interpreter than the one used by vscode (assuming you have both anaconda and python installed separately). Ensure they are using the same interpreter and then try, maybe?

Comment: yes, i have installed spyder as part of anaconda. Using the sys module I‘ve been able to find out that there are two different interpreters being used by running sys.executable() . I‘m assuming this is a duplicate question, but how do I change the interpreter in VScode to the one that‘s running in Spyder?

Comment: You can use the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) or (Cmd+Shift+P) and then select "Python: Select Interpreter". This will list available interpreters that are available that you can then use. 


Although the best way to do this is really to create a new virtual environment for the project you want and installing specific dependencies as you need in that environment - so you can keep the dependencies together, and also no pollute the system / common python installation. Also this ensures that your project's behavior is not dependent on the tool / IDE you use.

Comment: Thank you! (ctrl+shift+p) openend the menu i was looking for.